# fopen returning NULL when trying to open a bmp file (C++)?

Tags: c, visual-c++, file-io, fopen, bmp

```
FILE * in;
in = fopen("file1.bmp", "rb"); 
if (in == NULL) {
    perror("file1.bmp");
    return ;
}
```

Why is it that I am not able to open the *.bmp file. **fopen() is returning NULL**.

Can anyone kindly help me how to successfully open a BMP file. Should I use some other C++ function. If yes, plz let me know. An example would be very helpful. I am using VC++ in  VS2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no difference between opening a .bmp file and opening any other kind of file (except the binary mode issue, which you've got right). It's failing for one of the many reasons file opens fail, probably one of the issues Chris has specified below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file does not exist, or you can't read from it (maybe file permissions)?
You might have a working directory issue. Try opening the file with a fully qualified path.
Also this is a plain C question

Comment: I bet my 2 cents that he hasn't configured the working directory on his IDE.

Comment: fopen is just returning NULL. No specific error msgs as a clue. Yes, I even tried by providing full absolute path to BMP file. I right clicked on the BMP file & verified that it has the read Onlt checkbox selected. Not able to guess what else might be the reason.

Comment: If fopen returns `NULL`, then the only  options are either file permissions, file does not exist, or a file system error.  
If you are programming under windows, make sure to escape backslashes or use normal slashes as path separators, for example: `fopen("c:\\test\\file1.bmp", "rb");` or `fopen("c:/test/file1.bmp", "rb");`

Comment: Thank you it solved my issue by giving full path escape backslashes. It would be good if you can also let me ow how do I configure my VS2008 such that it can pick up the parent path say"C:\\Test\\ even without me giving the absolute path to BMP file. Point to note is that the .cpp file and BMP file are in different folders.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
FILE * in;
in = fopen("file1.bmp", "rb"); 
if (in == NULL) {
    perror("file1.bmp");
    printf("Error %d \n", errno);
    return ;
}
```

}

using this way see `errno` and find its meaning from here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html